# IFRAME won't load content from page

Tags: html, iframe

`iframe` won't load content from this link
http://hotlantatravel.paycationonline.com/index.asp

When I try to `iframe` it, nothing happens, why?

Answer (score 2):

That site is sending an HTTP response header

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

telling the browser that this resource should not be displayed in any kind of frames, unless those frames are on the same domain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options